# SharePoint 2010 and Word 2010 Multilanguage Managed Metadata issue

Tags: managed-metadata, office-integration, multilingual

We have some issues related to a SharePoint 2010 solution. It’s an Intranet site Collection with multi language support on UI, Managed Metadata and document content. The PC’s are set up with Windows 7, IE9 and Office 2010.

An example of Managed metadata used: Document type

**English - Norwegian**

Guideline - Direktiv
Procedure - Prosedyre
Instruction - Instruks
Appendix - Vedlegg

In a Library for Steering Documents, Word templates has been created. The templates contains QuickParts as placeholders for SharePoint columns that should be printed on the document.

When a user want to create a new document, he/she choose correct template from the SharePoint menu. The document opens in Word and a Document Information Panel occurs. The user fills in the fields. QuickParts placeholders is updated accordingly. But the language for the content seems to be “randomly” chosen.

We will like to know how it is possible to control the language that is in use. We thought that the current display language in SharePoint should control which language that should be sent to the newly created Word document. We have tried a couple of set up. It seems like it is the Office installation language that controls the language for the SharePoint provided data.

To be clear, the change has to be done in a controlled and easy way. Users should be able to edit both Languages, just by selecting Language either in SharePoint or Word.

The question is: "How to Control the Language used for Managed Metadat when integrating SharePoint 2010 and Word 2010?

Comment: As far as I can tell the language of the underlying SPWeb is important.